# In OS X app, how to use auto layout when a window is created programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

My OS X App tries to create a window programmatically as below (suggested by another SO question I saw earlier):

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {

    override func loadView() {

        let view = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0,0,300,100))
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.borderWidth = 2
        view.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        self.view = view
   }
}

let viewController = MyViewController()
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: someFrame, styleMask: [.resizable, .closable, .miniaturizable, .titled], backing: NSBackingStoreType.buffered, defer: false)

window.contentView?.addSubview(viewController.view)
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

I can successfully create windows by the code above. However, my question is... how to make the view created in `loadView` inside the view controller to be the same size as the window's content view?

Right now, it creates the view with fixed numbers (0, 0, 300, 100). How to make this view to be the same size as the window by using Auto layout, so when the window is resized, this view will resize automatically too?

Comment: why can't you use constraints between window.contentview and viewcontroller.view? Just use constraints to pin viewcontroller.view's top, left, right and bottom to window.contentview

Answer (score -1):

One would thing that Apple would document such a thing. And indeed they did:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Comment: I know how to use Auto Layouts but not in my code above. How do you get the window's contentView here to do the auto layout constraints? I am not asking about how to do auto layout in general. Thanks.